# Jsoncpp и С++ Builder

Tags: json, c++builder

При попытке скомпилить этот код :

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <iostream>
#include "json/json.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
using namespace std;
using namespace Json;
#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        Value value;
        Reader reader;
        bool is_ok = reader.parse("{\"test\":\"text\"}",value,false);
        cout<<is_ok<<endl;
        return 0;

}
```

Выдает ошибки типа :

```
[Linker Error] Unresolved external 'Json::Value::~Value()' referenced from C:\USERS\USER\DESKTOP\JSON TEST\UNIT1.OBJ
```

Как и чем с этим бороться?

Comment: перетянул cpp файл, но теперь ругается на его код. хотя jsoncpp.cpp генерировал так как описано на оф. репозиторие –  Vladuysha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Линкер видит только заголовочные файлы. Подключи *.cpp файлы этой библиотеки себе в проект. Или *.lib файл если библиотека подключается статически.